# Vector changes value unexpected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, stl

I am making a little game (just console) and my vectors don't act like I think they have to. One Value of the vector just changes and I don't know why. The Code shown below is part where this bug come from, I have deleted the rest of the code where these 2 vectors show up and the bug still appears and I DONT KNOW WHY!!
This part of the code is responsible for letting the Enemy spread to a random direction.

```
/**in this part the first value of the 2 vectors are created 
(only once, I've tested it)**/
if(moves == 0){
    int randomNum1 = (rand() % HEIGHT)+1;
    int randomNum2 = (rand() % WIDTH)+1;
    _EnemysY.push_back(randomNum1);
    _EnemysX.push_back(randomNum2);
}
/**_Enemy vectors have normal values. For instance: _EnemysX[0]
is 23 and _EnemysY[0] is 12**/
/**In this part, the Enemy spreads in a random direction**/
if (moves > 3){
    //save Enemys at the border here (those who can move)
    std::vector<int> topX;
    std::vector<int> topY;
    std::vector<int> botX;
    std::vector<int> botY;
    std::vector<int> rigX;
    std::vector<int> rigY;
    std::vector<int> lefX;
    std::vector<int> lefY;
/**here, I wanna save all Fields of the Enemy where it can spread to:**/
    for (Uint it = 0; it < _EnemysY.size(); it++){          
/**_EnemysY is still normal, but _EnemysX is like: 86BF163E0**/     
        if (_map[_EnemysY[it]-1][_EnemysX[it]] == _Grenade || _map[_EnemysY[it]-1][_EnemysX[it]] == _Field){
            topY.push_back(_EnemysY[it]);
            topX.push_back(_EnemysX[it]);
        }
        if (_map[_EnemysY[it]+1][_EnemysX[it]] == _Grenade || _map[_EnemysY[it]+1][_EnemysX[it]] == _Field){
            botY.push_back(_EnemysY[it]);
            botX.push_back(_EnemysX[it]);
        }
        if (_map[_EnemysY[it]][_EnemysX[it]-1] == _Grenade || _map[_EnemysY[it]][_EnemysX[it]-1] == _Field){
            lefX.push_back(_EnemysX[it]);
            lefY.push_back(_EnemysY[it]);
        }
        if (_map[_EnemysY[it]][_EnemysX[it]+1] == _Grenade || _map[_EnemysY[it]][_EnemysX[it]+1] == _Field){
            rigX.push_back(_EnemysX[it]);
            rigY.push_back(_EnemysY[it]);
        }
    }

/**and here is a random direction created and the programm 
chooses which Field it will spread to: **/
    for (;;){
        int ranDir = (rand() % 4)+1;
        if (ranDir == 1 && !topY.empty()){
            int temp = (rand() % topY.size())+1;
            _EnemysY.push_back(topY[temp]);
            _EnemysX.push_back(topX[temp]);
            return true;
        }
        if (ranDir == 2 && !botY.empty()){
            int temp = (rand() % botY.size())+1;
            _EnemysY.push_back(botY[temp]);
            _EnemysX.push_back(botX[temp]);
            return true;
        }
        if (ranDir == 3 && !lefY.empty()){
            int temp = (rand() % lefY.size())+1;
            _EnemysY.push_back(lefY[temp]);
            _EnemysX.push_back(lefX[temp]);
            return true;
        }
        if (ranDir == 4 && !rigY.empty()){
            int temp = (rand() % rigY.size())+1;
            _EnemysY.push_back(rigY[temp]);
            _EnemysX.push_back(rigX[temp]);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere do you check if your vector indices are within bounds.  I suggest temporarily changing to call at() instead of using [].  This will verify if you're going out of bounds (the at() function will throw an exception if the index is out of bounds).  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, that is not the problem there, it just changes the value of _EnemysX when it enters the for-loop :(

Comment: What is the type of `_map`?

Comment: @Aemmel - Whenever a value changes "by itself", it usually means a data or buffer overrun.  Since the code shown doesn't use pointers but does use vectors, plus uses vector::operator[], then the suggestion of using at() to see if all values are in bounds is valid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok, I tried it but it didn't work, you can see where the value changes in the comments in the code above. Strangly enough the same technique is used in my code before :/

Comment: @Aemmel You're indexing it, it can't be a `char`. Maybe the values it holds are `char`, but the `_map` itself has some other `type`. What is it and how are you populating it? Can you post the bare minimum code that compiles and reproduces the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your comments.  EnemysY is a vector.  What value in that vector changes?  EnemysY[0]?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, until the bug happens there is no variable pushed back into the vector (checked it with printing the size of it several times)

Comment: @Aemmel - Now I am confused.  Is the vector valid, but a value in the vector (one of the indexed items) has changed?  Or is the entire vector object invalid?  It is hard to pin down exactly what the problem is given your descriptions.

Comment: @Aemmel it's time for you to post compilable and runnable code. Isolate only the parts that populate the vectors and the map. Make sure the issue still reproduces in the new code sample.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie First of all: I'm pretty confused to. And (just figured it out 5 seconds ago) the latest value of the vector changes.

Comment: @Andrei OK, I'll quickly produce an GitHub post with my whole code, and please: don't be too shocked, I'm quite new to this whole thing

Comment: @Aemmel We neither want nor need your *whole* code. Writing a small piece of code that reproduces a problem is part of the skills you need to learn. It might also lead you to discover the cause of the problem yourself.

Comment: @Andrei But I already did, the problem happens THERE. (but because I've read your answer too late, here: https://github.com/Aemmel/ConsoleGame1/tree/master :) )

Comment: @Aemmel - Your map is a two dimensional array.  Absolutely nowhere in your code that I see do you check if any of those accesses to map is within bounds.  I don't know if you didn't know this or not, but C++ does not check array boundaries, and will not automatically let you know if you're out of bounds.  Any access out of bounds can cause undefined behavior in other parts of the program.  Also, I would suggest not to name your type "map", as there already is a std::map<> class in C++.

Comment: @Aemmel - Your map::EntityMovable() function has undefined behavior.  You are using boolean variables that may or may not have been set when you test them.  B1, B2, B3, etc. have undefined values when you test them.  You should initialize your variables to known values before you test them.  Otherwise there is no way to run your program in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: thank you Andrei and PaulMcKenzie for your time, your answers didn't solve the problem, but they were still usefull. :)

Now to the answer of the problem:

Alright! I'm a complete douchebag! Because what I didn't print in the code above, was my std::cout s for my variables and I accidentally wrote: "std::cout << ... << std:cout << ... std::endl" and for some reason the second "std::cout" caused a bug, where it printed out an ridiculously high number. So my code in general (without the cout s) works fine, but I still changed some things which you said.

Answer (score 0):

First off, why not have a `struct` describing the "enemy", including its position (via two fields `X` and `Y`)? It would improve the code a bit and avoid the need for two vectors that are meaningless if separated.

On topic:

```
int temp = (rand() % rigY.size())+1;
_EnemysY.push_back(rigY[temp]);
```

`rand() % rigY.size()` will give you a number in the interval [0, `rigY.size()` ). You then add 1 to both sides so `temp` would be in the interval [1, `rigY.size()` ].

But `rigY[rigY.size()]` is not a valid element in the vector...

Comment: Also, are you certain your two vectors have the same size? Again, this problem would be solved by having a struct or class describing your entities.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll try that, but it still doesn't really give me an answer to my question: "why is the one vector just changing it's value from for instance 23 to 86BF163E0?" I just can't figure it out. (I have this problem for 1 week now >.< )

Comment: @Aemmel the index `it` goes from 0 to `_EnemysY.size()` but you use it to also iterate through `_EnemysX`. Are you certain that value was initialized? If so, you can add a data breakpoint and see where the value is changed.

Comment: yes, _EnemysX is initialized and I have also used this technique in this program before (also vectors) and it works perfectly fine. And btw: whats a data breaking point? (I am only programming for 5 months now ^^)

Comment: @Aemmel Then add a data breakpoints on the element that changes and see what line of code changes it. In any case, "works perfectly fine" is not a guarantee of anything. Your code is *not* standard compliant: you are accessing elements outside the array bounds (see my answer) and you are also using reserved identifiers (the ones that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter and are reserved for C++ implementations).

Comment: If you mean printing all variables out with "data breakpoint", then I already did and thats why I know where the value changes. And I know that it's reserved for C++ implemantations, but these variables are private membervariables, so it's ok to mark them like this (I've checked my books and the internet ^^)

Comment: @Aemmel What do you mean "printing all variables"??? Most IDEs have the ability to set a data breakpoint which gets triggered when data at some location in memory is changed.

Comment: @Aemmel - A data breakpoint means that you give the debugger the address of a variable (or if in scope, the actual variable name).  Then you direct the debugger to stop when that variable or that memory location changes.  When the debugger stops, you look at the call stack to see what got you to that point and what functions were called to cause the change in data.

Comment: @Andrei Oh, now I get what you meant, and yes, I already did it and it didn't help me out (like I said, I know the few lines in which the bug happens)

Comment: @Aemmel it's not necessarily about the lines but about the "context", i.e. what were the values in the other variables or why did the code change that value...

Comment: @Aemmel - You don't know *what* changed the variable.  That is what the breakpoint is for, so that you know what changed the variable.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Andrei I am using Visual Studio 2012 Prof.

Comment: You're using Visual Studio, and you're saying that setting a data breakpoint doesn't break???  Either you didn't set it up correctly, or some other issue.  I have been using Visual Studio for 15 years now, and setting data breakpoints always reveal the reason for a changed variable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this should probably be moved to chat